# What were the boons/curses received by Indrajit?

Tags: curse, boon, indrajit

some questions relating to Indrajit's killing:

(1) Could he only be killed by someone who didn't sleep for 14 years?  did that person also have to be celibate for 14 years?

(2) Would he have become invincible if he had completed the Yagna to Pratyangira Devi?

(3) Did Adisesha incarnate as Lakshmana to kill Indrajit because he married Sesha's daughter without his permission?

All info taken from

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indrajit